# Oracle:Cursor Procedure: sum 2 tables with join

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, join, cursor, sum

I have 3 tables.

Table1

```
|Obj_id|Obj_Name|
----------------
|A     |     AAA|
|B     |     BBB|
|C     |     CCC|
```

Table2

```
|Obj_id|Amount1|
----------------
|A     |   1000|
|C     |     20|
|A     |    100|
|B     |     50|
|C     |     10|
```

Table3

```
|Obj_id|Amount2|
----------------
|B     |    500|
|C     |     10|
|C     |     40|
```

Now I need to create a procedure "report" that returns a cursor like below

Report

```
|Obj_Name|Amount1|Amount2|Obj_id|
---------------------------------
|AAA     |   1100|      0|A     |
|BBB     |     50|    500|B     |
|CCC     |     30|     50|C     |
```

I googled everywhere but there is no matching answer.

Comment: Where does the `sum` fit into it - do you have multiple values per `obj_id` in `table2/3`? Have you got the basic query working and just need to figure out how to return it from a procedure? (If you're really *returning* then it's a function; not sure if you mean that or a procedure with an `out` parameter).

Comment: It's my mistake with the sum example. I've fixed the question the match my case. Function or Procedure is ok if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  T1.Obj_Name
  ,NVL(T2.Amount1,0) AS Amount1
  ,NVL(T3.Amount2,0) AS Amount2
  ,NVL(T1.Obj_id ,0) AS Obj_id
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Obj_id = T2.Obj_id
LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 ON T1.Obj_id = T3.Obj_id
ORDER BY T1.Obj_Name
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/25e6c/14)

**OUTPUT**

```
Obj_Name  Amount1  Amount2  Obj_id
AAA      1000       0       A
BBB       0        500      B
CCC      20        10       C
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT 
   T1.Obj_Name AS Obj_Name
  ,NVL(T2.Amount1,0) AS Amount1
  ,NVL(T3.Amount2,0) AS Amount2
  ,T1.Obj_id AS Obj_id
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Obj_id,SUM(Amount1) AS Amount1 FROM Table2 GROUP BY Obj_id) T2 ON T1.Obj_id = T2.Obj_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Obj_id,SUM(Amount2) AS Amount2 FROM Table3 GROUP BY Obj_id) T3 ON T1.Obj_id = T3.Obj_id
ORDER BY T1.Obj_Name;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO UPDATED**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd91d/17)

**OUTPUT**

```
OBJ_NAME AMOUNT1  AMOUNT2  OBJ_ID
AAA      1100       0      A
BBB      50         500    B
CCC      30         50     C
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I 've fixed the question to match my case. Hoping that you should give me another solution.

Comment: Yes, That's what I need. Now i just add "Open cursor for select ..." to complete procedure. You're like a god. Many thanks.